# Mongoose Caching a Part of a Referenced Subdoc on Creation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple schema with references. But I dont want to populate the referenced document on every query. Instead I want to cache a part (only a single attribute) on the referencing document.

A simple example schema:

```
User
  - displayName
  (....stuff....)

Posts
  - title
  - content
  - user (reference?)
```

When I used references and population on demand my PostSchema would look like:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    user: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
})
```

But I want to save (cache) **only the displayName** (not the other stuff in User) and the _id in Post **when it is created**. My thougts on that is to change the PostSchema as following:

```
user: {
    _id: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    displayName: String
}
```

on the creation of a post I do:

```
var post = new Post(req.body);
post.user._id = req.user._id;
post.user.displayName = req.user.displayName;
```

The problem with this is: It looks like now _id **is** the referenced user, leading to absurd user._id._id. Also my isCreator-middleware now needs to convert the _id to a string:

```
exports.isCreator = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.post.user._id.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()) {
        return res.status(403).send('User is not authorized');
    }
    next();
};
```

This cannot be the best solution. So my question is: What is best practice for this case?